# JavaFX Glass Detected - How to run code away from GUI Javafx

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, javafx

I am creating a new javafx application - my first time working with javafx. I am creating the GUI using FXML and creating a stage from this as follows:

> ```
> public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
>
>     Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));        
>     Scene scene = new Scene(root);        
>     stage.setScene(scene);
>     stage.show();
> }
> ```

My FXML has a single button which points to my MainController, an on its click the handleButton method is called:

> public class MainController implements Initializable {
>
> ```
> @FXML
> private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
>     System.out.println("You clicked me!");         
> }
> ```

The above code works fine, and the console prints out "You clicked me as expected". But what I want is a web request and other code to run:

> public class MainController implements Initializable {
>
> ```
> @FXML
> private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
>     System.out.println("You clicked me!"); 
>     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();        
> }
> ```

When I try to create the HTTP Client object inside my button handler I get the following error:

> run: You clicked me! Glass detected outstanding Java exception at
>   -[GlassViewDelegate sendJavaMouseEvent:]:src/com/sun/mat/ui/GlassViewDelegate.m:541
>   Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1440)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)  at
>   javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:6863)   at
>   javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:179)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:193)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:336)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.SkinBase$4.handle(SkinBase.java:329)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:64)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3328)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3168)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3123)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)    at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2265)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)    at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)

So my question is:

a) Why is this happening? Why does the creation of the HTTPClient throw this error when simple things like printlns and variable assignment works fine.

b) What is the correct way of handeling button clicks in javafx - in swing I would use a SwingWorker to do the core application work away from the GUI.

I look forward to any help!

Comment: Hi @fixulate please tell whether HTTPClient is made by you or by Apache (or by someone else).

Comment: Take a look at Concurrency in JavaFX: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm

Answer (score 2):

You need to move to an async HTTP client that can send the information back to the javaFX thread as its received, the UI thread does **not appreciate** being blocked, I suggest you look into the  [Task Runners of JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) or if you feel like going a little out further [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) and such.